# Is it idiomatic to use `impl<T> From<T> for Option<T>` in argument position?

Tags: rust

This trait is [implemented since 1.12.0](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-From%3CT%3E):

```
impl<T> From<T> for Option<T> {
    fn from(val: T) -> Option<T> {
        Some(val)
    }
}
```

How idiomatic is this as an argument? Consider this example:

```
fn do_things(parameters: &Foo, optional_argument: impl Into<Option<Duration>>) {
    let optional_argument = optional_argument.into();
    // use it...
}
```

If you see the documentation, it's (more or less) clear (if you know, that this trait is implemented). But if you see the code, you may be confused:

```
do_things(params, Duration::from_millis(100));
```

Is this fine to use or should it be avoided?

Comment: You may be interested in this threads: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5fu7pd/the_intooption_trick 
https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/556c0g/optional_arguments_in_rust_112 (TLDR: it's controversial)

Comment: How can this be answered objectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is uncommon, but reasonably easy to understand. If it's convenient in the context of your library's usage, it should be OK.

I think it's more common to have `do_stuff` and `do_stuff_with_timeout` functions.